# Adding two floating numbers

Tags: c

I was solving a problem in C while I came across another problem. Briefly while running the below code the output is 50.009998. How to correct the answer and why is this happening.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float x;
    x = 50.000000 + 0.010000;
    printf("%f\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: besides what @Acorn has suggested, to fix the code use double instead of float for more precision.

Comment: Try defining `double x;`. Or otherwise, unless you are actually interested to 6 decimals (that's %f default) you can set `printf("%0.2f\n", x);` that will limit your print to 2 decimals (that are not affected to float precision error)